# The bounty label is highlighted in mobile devices even if still not awarded

Tags: bug, status-review, design, bounty, mobile-web

I set up a bounty in [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55482552/sudden-delay-while-recording-audio-over-long-time-periods-inside-the-jvm) with a lot of research effort coming from another user last week. Today I've used my mobile browser to see it and award it to the single given answer (the question was currently accepted by the OP), then I've noticed the bounty label is highlighted even if it's not still awarded. This happens in Chrome and Firefox browsers (I haven't tried other choices):

> [image: Screenshot showing highlighted icon issue, even though bounty has not been awarded yet]
>
> [image: Screenshot showing highlighted icon issue, even though bounty has not been awarded yet, with "are you sure you want to award?" alert]

Later on, I've viewed the question from my desktop computer and it's properly displayed:

> [image: Screenshot showing grayed out icon, when bounty hasn't been awarded yet]

This must be a bug in the site.

Comment: [Mistagged as a feature request on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307438/the-buttons-for-awarding-a-bounty-should-be-lighter-in-colour-mobile-site). Uh, [animuson mistagged it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/307438/2).